In git, how to unset core.fileMode for each submodule?
here is the result of my attempt:
$
git submodule foreach --recursive "git config --unset core.fileMode"
Entering 'buildSrc'
fatal: run_command returned non-zero status for buildSrc

my questions are:

what's the cause of the non-zero status?
how to fix it?


$ git init test-git
$ cd test-git
$ git config core.fileMode
true
$ git config --unset core.fileMode; echo $?
0
$ git config --unset core.fileMode; echo $?
5

That is, you cannot unset value which is not set, Git returns an error code. This is the answer for your 1st question.
For the 2nd question: you need to ignore errors:
git submodule foreach --recursive "git config --unset core.fileMode || :"

: in shells means noop, "do nothing". I.e., the command is "git config --unset or do nothing in case of errors".

thanks a lot! that's kind of a design flaw, git should throw some error message

@tribbloid Perhaps it should have option -v/--verbose, but then it should also have -q/--quiet.
